# CFMail SMTP connection limit

Tags: coldfusion, smtp, coldfusion-8, cfmail

Currently using ColdFusion 8 enterprise on 32 bit linux box to send out our mail to a third party provider who do the delivery (relay). Currently we have maintain mail server connections checked in the ColdFusion admin but they'd like us to limit the connections to each one of their servers to 5 and I'm not sure if you can make ColdFusion do that, I'm pretty sure not, at least not officially...

Looking at a max of 4000 / minute being spooled but more likely in the region of 2000 / minute.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to "hack" ColdFusion to limit the amount of connections it creates and maintains (in an xml file within lib or SERVER-INF somewhere maybe?)
2. How much performance loss would you expect from not maintaining the connections?

If anyone has any experience with this it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does "Mail Delivery Threads" on the Mail spool settings not do this?

Comment: From the docs it's not 100% clear, but, it's certainly worth lowering to see if it helps. It suggests more that it's processes on the box it limits, but, in term that could be the thing I'm after. We did have it 100 so I've dropped it to 25 (default out the box is 10) to see if that eases the possible issue.

Comment: If you only have 5 threads, you can only have five connections as I understand it.

Comment: Great Tip!  I'll try this out the next time I'm working with Cfmail

Answer (score 0):

if the above doesn't give you what you want, then you can always use the [javax.mail libraries](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/package-summary.html).  Those libraries give you a lot of flexibility and can generally configure it how you want to.  Of course, this option works best when your a java developer.